# How to deactivate "right click" on WPF Webbrowser Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I can't seem to find an answer to this.
Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Here is the code of a utility class that allows you to deactivate WPF's WebBrowser context menu. It also allows you to suppress script errors ([WPF WebBrowser control - how to supress script errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138199/wpf-webbrowser-control-how-to-supress-script-errors)) and change IE's [DOCHOSTUIFLAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753277.aspx).

Usage sample:

```
public partial class Player : Window
{
    private WebBrowserHostUIHandler _wbHandler;

    public Player()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        _wbHandler = new WebBrowserHostUIHandler(MyWebBrower);
        _wbHandler.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Utility code:

```
public class WebBrowserHostUIHandler : Native.IDocHostUIHandler
{
    private const uint E_NOTIMPL = 0x80004001;
    private const uint S_OK = 0;
    private const uint S_FALSE = 1;

    public WebBrowserHostUIHandler(WebBrowser browser)
    {
        if (browser == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("browser");

        Browser = browser;
        browser.LoadCompleted += OnLoadCompleted;
        browser.Navigated += OnNavigated;
        IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = true;
        Flags |= HostUIFlags.ENABLE_REDIRECT_NOTIFICATION;
    }

    public WebBrowser Browser { get; private set; }
    public HostUIFlags Flags { get; set; }
    public bool IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool ScriptErrorsSuppressed { get; set; }

    private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSilent(Browser, ScriptErrorsSuppressed);
    }

    private void OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Native.ICustomDoc doc = Browser.Document as Native.ICustomDoc;
        if (doc != null)
        {
            doc.SetUIHandler(this);
        }
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu(int dwID, Native.POINT pt, object pcmdtReserved, object pdispReserved)
    {
        return IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled ? S_FALSE : S_OK;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo(ref Native.DOCHOSTUIINFO info)
    {
        info.dwFlags = (int)Flags;
        info.dwDoubleClick = 0;
        return S_OK;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowUI(int dwID, object activeObject, object commandTarget, object frame, object doc)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.HideUI()
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.UpdateUI()
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.EnableModeless(bool fEnable)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.OnDocWindowActivate(bool fActivate)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.OnFrameWindowActivate(bool fActivate)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.ResizeBorder(Native.COMRECT rect, object doc, bool fFrameWindow)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.TranslateAccelerator(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, ref Guid group, int nCmdID)
    {
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetOptionKeyPath(string[] pbstrKey, int dw)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetDropTarget(object pDropTarget, out object ppDropTarget)
    {
        ppDropTarget = null;
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.GetExternal(out object ppDispatch)
    {
        ppDispatch = Browser.ObjectForScripting;
        return S_OK;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.TranslateUrl(int dwTranslate, string strURLIn, out string pstrURLOut)
    {
        pstrURLOut = null;
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    uint Native.IDocHostUIHandler.FilterDataObject(IDataObject pDO, out IDataObject ppDORet)
    {
        ppDORet = null;
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    public static void SetSilent(WebBrowser browser, bool silent)
    {
        Native.IOleServiceProvider sp = browser.Document as Native.IOleServiceProvider;
        if (sp != null)
        {
            Guid IID_IWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
            Guid IID_IWebBrowser2 = new Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11d0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E");

            object webBrowser;
            sp.QueryService(ref IID_IWebBrowserApp, ref IID_IWebBrowser2, out webBrowser);
            if (webBrowser != null)
            {
                webBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.PutDispProperty, null, webBrowser, new object[] { silent });
            }
        }
    }
}

internal static class Native
{
    [ComImport, Guid("BD3F23C0-D43E-11CF-893B-00AA00BDCE1A"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IDocHostUIHandler
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        uint ShowContextMenu(int dwID, POINT pt, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pcmdtReserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pdispReserved);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint GetHostInfo(ref DOCHOSTUIINFO info);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint ShowUI(int dwID, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object activeObject, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object commandTarget, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object frame, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object doc);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint HideUI();

        [PreserveSig]
        uint UpdateUI();

        [PreserveSig]
        uint EnableModeless(bool fEnable);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint OnDocWindowActivate(bool fActivate);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint OnFrameWindowActivate(bool fActivate);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint ResizeBorder(COMRECT rect, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object doc, bool fFrameWindow);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint TranslateAccelerator(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, ref Guid group, int nCmdID);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint GetOptionKeyPath([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] string[] pbstrKey, int dw);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint GetDropTarget([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pDropTarget, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppDropTarget);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint GetExternal([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] out object ppDispatch);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint TranslateUrl(int dwTranslate, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string strURLIn, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pstrURLOut);

        [PreserveSig]
        uint FilterDataObject(IDataObject pDO, out IDataObject ppDORet);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DOCHOSTUIINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public int dwFlags;
        public int dwDoubleClick;
        public IntPtr dwReserved1;
        public IntPtr dwReserved2;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct COMRECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("3050F3F0-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface ICustomDoc
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetUIHandler(IDocHostUIHandler pUIHandler);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IOleServiceProvider
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        uint QueryService([In] ref Guid guidService, [In] ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] out object ppvObject);
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum HostUIFlags
{
    DIALOG = 0x00000001,
    DISABLE_HELP_MENU = 0x00000002,
    NO3DBORDER = 0x00000004,
    SCROLL_NO = 0x00000008,
    DISABLE_SCRIPT_INACTIVE = 0x00000010,
    OPENNEWWIN = 0x00000020,
    DISABLE_OFFSCREEN = 0x00000040,
    FLAT_SCROLLBAR = 0x00000080,
    DIV_BLOCKDEFAULT = 0x00000100,
    ACTIVATE_CLIENTHIT_ONLY = 0x00000200,
    OVERRIDEBEHAVIORFACTORY = 0x00000400,
    CODEPAGELINKEDFONTS = 0x00000800,
    URL_ENCODING_DISABLE_UTF8 = 0x00001000,
    URL_ENCODING_ENABLE_UTF8 = 0x00002000,
    ENABLE_FORMS_AUTOCOMPLETE = 0x00004000,
    ENABLE_INPLACE_NAVIGATION = 0x00010000,
    IME_ENABLE_RECONVERSION = 0x00020000,
    THEME = 0x00040000,
    NOTHEME = 0x00080000,
    NOPICS = 0x00100000,
    NO3DOUTERBORDER = 0x00200000,
    DISABLE_EDIT_NS_FIXUP = 0x00400000,
    LOCAL_MACHINE_ACCESS_CHECK = 0x00800000,
    DISABLE_UNTRUSTEDPROTOCOL = 0x01000000,
    HOST_NAVIGATES = 0x02000000,
    ENABLE_REDIRECT_NOTIFICATION = 0x04000000,
    USE_WINDOWLESS_SELECTCONTROL = 0x08000000,
    USE_WINDOWED_SELECTCONTROL = 0x10000000,
    ENABLE_ACTIVEX_INACTIVATE_MODE = 0x20000000,
    DPI_AWARE = 0x40000000
}
```

Comment: This works for me on Windows 10 (WPF web browser). Should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Reference mshtml

```
using mshtml;
```

Then you can do this by accessing the document:

```
MainBrowser.Navigate("https://www.domain.com");

 MainBrowser.LoadCompleted += (o, args) =>
 {
    var doc = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event) MainBrowser.Document;
    doc.oncontextmenu += obj => false;
 };
```

Comment: Weird.  It works for only one right-click, the 2nd right-click the popup is back!

Answer (score 4):

From the internal WebBrowserSite class:

```
int UnsafeNativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu(int dwID, NativeMethods.POINT pt, object pcmdtReserved, object pdispReserved)
{
    // Returning S_FALSE will allow the native control to do default processing,
    // i.e., execute the shortcut key. Returning S_OK will cancel the context menu

    return NativeMethods.S_FALSE;
}
```

Hard-baked, you cannot override this. Putting the Winforms WebBrower inside a WindowsFormsHost would be a workaround, it's got a smarter implementation of this method that uses the IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled property and allows you to create your own context menu.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I had a unique problem in that I wanted/needed to use the newer CSProj file format with the .Net Core SDK but it has a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2920) with not being able to reference extension libraries, such as mshtml. So I finally found a solution that's **possible without a reference to mshtml**.

Some inspiration came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464764/2646868 where the user cast the `WebBrowser.Document` property to `dynamic`.

Assuming webView is the name of your `WebBrowser` control, hook up the `LoadCompleted` event like such:

```cs
private void webView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic document = webView.Document;
    document.oncontextmenu += new Func<bool>(() => false);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly :)

Comment: Unfortunately, once you select some text, the context menu is back.

Comment: Is this supposed to work for System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser ? On my side is giving: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'oncontextmenu'. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: It's been so long since I've looked at this, but yes I believe it's `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`. Did you cast the `WebBrowser` or the `Document` property to `dynamic`?

Answer (score 0):

Digging graves it seems, but...

Based on e.g. answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979961/4537127 get `IWebBrowser2` interface, then get `DWebBrowserEvents2_Event` interface, and attach handler to DocumentComplete event

```
SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_Event wbEvents = (SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)myWebBrowser2;
wbEvents.DocumentComplete += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(OnWebBrowserDocumentComplete);
```

(Above must to be done only once on WebBrowser LoadCompleted event, so add some logic to run it only on first one)

And then in this handler, run sone JavaScript to attach event listener to document, and as bonus, to the iframe in this document

```
private void OnWebBrowserDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    /* try-catch wrap this if you get e.g. DISP_E_EXCEPTION */
    MyBrowser.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[]
    {
        "document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);" +
        "var frm = document.getElementById('frm');" +
        "frm.onload = function() { frm.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false); };",
        "JavaScript"
    });
}
```

This will work even if the iframe content is changed. I use this with DITA WebHelp classic running in WPF WebBrowser.

And no mshtml reference needed.