# WebBrowser Control - Prevent Right-Click

Tags: c#, reporting-services, browser, webbrowser-control

In my application, I have a form that contains a browser control in which I display an SSRS report. I would like to prevent the user from right-clicking in the browser control and being shown the popup menu. Ideally I'd like the right-click to do nothing. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Is this windows forms or WPF? Is this the WebBrowser control or the Report control?

Comment: If you have implemented a browser control, just to show a report, in a SSRS web-control, why don't you use Windows Report control and avoid browser control in this scenario (if its just like that)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled equal to false. You will probably also want to set AllowWebBrowserDrop equal to false too so they cant drag a url into the app and have it load.

```
        webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
```

Comment: Works for the Winforms WebBrowser, not the WPF version.

Comment: The WPF version seems to be chiefly underfeatured. I personally end up using Forms' WebBrowser through a WindowsFormsHost control almost every time.

Comment: @Kaganar Only problem with that approach is you're limited to something like IE 5/6-level capabilities for the HTML renderer, unless you set up registry entities to tell IE to use a later version like 10/11 when your app plug into ieframe.dll.

Answer (score 4):

for any case, winform or wpf:

```
     private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            ((WebBrowser)sender).InvokeScript("eval", "$(document).contextmenu(function() {    return false;        });");
}
```

Comment: This is sort of the best answer, as the most elegant one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699086/592212) has problems (at least I've experienced crashes), when WebBrowser (WPF) was included in custom control. Requires jQuery thought.

Comment: works perfectly, without requiring any changes to either the loaded page or application's own design or registry :)

Answer (score 2):

For WPF ===>

wbBrowser.ContextMenu.IsEnabled = false;

Comment: This works only if you assign first a ContextMenu, otherwise it is null by default. The question is about preventing context menu from the displayed web page, not this WPF context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution work on my project (WPF - MVVM):

**Important add reference**: Microsoft.mshtml

Implement event: webBrowser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_LoadCompleted;

```
using mshtml;

private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    object doc = webBrowser.Document;
    HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event evn2 = doc as HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event;
    HTMLDocumentEvents_Event evn = doc as HTMLDocumentEvents_Event;
    evn.oncontextmenu += new HTMLDocumentEvents_oncontextmenuEventHandler(Evn_oncontextmenu);
    evn2.oncontextmenu += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_oncontextmenuEventHandler(Evn2_oncontextmenu);
}

private bool Evn2_oncontextmenu(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
{
    return false;
}

private bool Evn_oncontextmenu()
{
    return false;
}
```

Hope helpful.