# Disable WebBrowser contextmenu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

How can I disable the standard-contextmenu of the WPF WebBrowser-Control?

Comment: Good question, +1up. This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507734/disable-context-menu-on-webbrowser-in-wpf

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deactivate "right click" on WPF Webbrowser Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412915/how-to-deactivate-right-click-on-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using mshtml;

```
    private mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event documentEvents;
```

in constructor or xaml set your LoadComplete event:

```
   webBrowser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_LoadCompleted;
```

then in that method create your new webbrowser document object and view the available properties and create new events as follows:

```
private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    documentEvents = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)webBrowserChat.Document; // this will access the events properties as needed
    documentEvents.oncontextmenu += webBrowserChat_ContextMenuOpening;
}

private bool webBrowserChat_ContextMenuOpening(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
{
    return false; // ContextMenu wont open
    // return true;  ContextMenu will open
    // Here you can create your custom contextmenu or whatever you want
}
```