# WPF WebView2 - not able to disable Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

**Environment**: `Windows 10 Pro - ver. 1903`, `VS2019 latest version`, `WPF Core`

When I have a manual control on an `HTML` page displayed inside [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) control, I can disable the context menu by simply adding `oncontextmunu={return false;}` as an attribute to `<body>` tag. But in most cases the web page is displayed based on user interaction (what page user navigates to etc.).

**Question**: How can we disable to context menu of a webpage displayed in WebView2 control?

**Remarks**:

1. I have noticed that in some cases where a JavaScript is loaded along with a webpage, the `oncontextmunu={return false;}` does not disable the context menu even if I add this attribute programmatically to the `body` tag of loaded page. I see `AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled` property of [Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/dotnet/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2settings) class but `VS2019` does not recognize any such property for `WebView2`.
2. There was a similar issue on the old `WebBrowser` control of WPF as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5507734/1232087) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412915/1232087), and I have the similar situation for WebView2.
3. According to bullet 5 of this [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/releasenotes#08314) the issue was resolved. But the solution there seems to be related to `C++` while I'm using `C#`. Maybe, there is an alternative.

Comment: Use: webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false; AFTER the CoreWebView has been initialized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you override the ContextMenu that appears when right clicking on WebView2 Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624373/how-do-you-override-the-contextmenu-that-appears-when-right-clicking-on-webview2)

Comment: @PoulBak Your suggestion of using `webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false; AFTER the CoreWebView has been initialized` worked (thank you) for my particular case. Not sure if it would work or not in other cases. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62662908/1232087) by a member of MS Edge WebView2 team, their team does not yet have full support for customizing the context menu. But there are workaround - such as the one you demoed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62732034/1232087). Ref for [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987060/1232087)

Answer (score 16):

Mostly, the reason for disabling the Context Menu is for **preventing the End-User from inspecting the page source.** Thus, we should also disable the accelerator keys using both instructions:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled = false;
webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
```

since the **End-User can use Ctrl+Shift-C and F12 for DevTools**
[check Accelerator Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.arebrowseracceleratorkeysenabled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1245.22)

Comment: Perfect! I'd forgotten about the keyboard shortcuts. Good catch!

Comment: I wouldn't have caught keyboard shortcuts fix; this was an excellent suggestion to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but another option is -

webView2.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;

Comment: Please highlight the code block.